# Python Selenium driver.find_element().text returns empty string, but text is visible in the driver.page_source

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape some titles of the videos and to do so I'm using Selenium, but I've encountered a problem. `driver.find_element().text` returns empty string, but title is for sure located in given XPATH. Here is the fragment of the page source returned by driver.page_source:

```
<div class="title"><a href="/f/4n3x7e31hpwxm8"target="_blank">Big.Sky.S03E01.ITA.WEBDL.1080p</a></div>
```

To find the title I am trying to use:

```
hoverable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="videojs"]/div[1]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(hoverable).perform()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
title_from_url = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/a'))).text
title_from_url = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/a'
    ).text.casefold()
```

From what I've read it could be caused by the fact that the page might not be fully loaded (I wasn't using any wait condition here). After that I've tried to add a wait condition and even time.sleep(), but it didn't change anything. <mini question: how would proper wait staitment look like here?>

Edit:
I think the problem is caused, because title is showing up only when mouse is in the player area. I think some mouse movement will be needed here, but I have tried to move mouse into the player area and for some time it is working but after a while there is a moment when title will disappear too fast. Is there a way to use find_element() while also moving mouse?

Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards,
Ed.

Example site: https://mixdrop.to/e/4n3x7e31hpwxm8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for element to be completely loaded before extracting it text content. `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits should be used for that.
This should wait in case the element is visible on the page and the locator is correct:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

title_from_url = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "title")]/a'))).text
```

**UPD**
In case the element content is dynamically changes and we need to hover over that element to make the desired text to appear there, we can simulate the mouse hover action with the help of `ActionChains` module.
The tool-tip etc. will not disappear until you perform some click etc. on that page. So, just performing a background action of `driver.find_element()` will not affect that text.
**UPD2**
The title element is not visible. It becomes visible only by hovering over the player.
Here I'm performing such hovering and then getting the title text:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url = "https://mixdrop.to/e/4n3x7e31hpwxm8"
driver.get(url)

player = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'player')))
actions.move_to_element(player).perform()
title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "title")]/a')))
print(title.text)
```

The output is:

```
Big.Sky.S03E01.ITA.WEBDL.1080p
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, I've tried to implement it earlier but it don't solve the issue. I think that the issue here is caused by the fact that title is dynamically loaded by JS  when you move your mouse around the player and I will need some sort of mouse action to reveal it, but then the problem is that sometimes it will disappear before find_element() would process it. Is there any way to use find_element() during mouse movements?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It would be better if you shared your actual code with the link to the page you actually working on so we could perform basic debugging.  Without that we can only guess and give global suggestions, not a precise, tested, working code.

Comment: There is a site at the end of my post, but here it is once again https://mixdrop.to/e/4n3x7e31hpwxm8. I will also update the code to current one.

Comment: Video title element is becoming visible only by hovering over the player with a mouse. I updated the answer with such code

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect its because of sync issue. You can use selenium waits.Let it be implicit of explicit.

Implicit:
objdriver.implicitely_wait(float)

Explicit:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

objwait=WebDriverWait(driver,float,poll_frequency=float,ignored_exception=float)

objelement=objwait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"Your XPATH")))